# Building workflow into existing applications

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, akka.net

I have a system developed on MVC and require an additional module to be added to this system. The additional module seems to be more workflow based with approvals and notifications to go out once x is completed to let Y know they have something to do and once Y he needs to upload proof and let the client know that the status has changed.... along that trend.

I have read up on K2 and their dismal pricing structure is a bit of a turn off. I also think it may be slightly overkill for this singular module of the application.

I see Microsoft flow as a potential means of solving this problem, but I am not too fond of the idea of setting up flows in a "third party"  application.

Then the other thing I touched on was AKKA.net (https://getakka.net/articles/intro/what-is-akka.html) with its Actor modeling, but to be honest the documentation is not what I consider "light" reading so i find it hard to gage its suitability.

**I guess I have two questions.**

has anyone tried to do something similar using AKKA.net and would it be suitable, where would one start?

Is there a way to programmatically incorporate Microsoft Flow into the existing application?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't have experience with it myself, but I've been keeping [NService Bus](https://particular.net/nservicebus) in mind for when I need long running workflows.

Comment: "programmatically incorporate Microsoft Flow"  No, it's a standalone system that runs flowcharts in the cloud.